# How do you nest jquery event listeners in a way where one needs the other to go off first?

Tags: jquery

I am making a website that has a video and a link, when you click the link, it plays the video, and when the video ends, it replaces the video with a div. The catch is I am trying to have multiple links (a nav bar) that all display and play the same video, but when the video is finished, a different div will be displayed (and other stuff happens) depending on which link you ariginally clicked. The code goes roughly in this format:

```
$("#lStore").click(function() {'
    //video is displayed
    $('#right').on('ended',function(){
        //video is replaced
    });
$(this).unbind("click");
});
```

However, like I mentioned earlier there are several of these for all the links (the same code is repeated 4 times with slightly different code to diifer the divs being placed and faded out). The issue when the first link is clicked, it works perfectly, but then when the next link is clicked, (and after the previous div is removed) it runs the new link AND the previous link's code that is under .on('ended, which is problematic (multiple divs are directly on top of each other). Is there a "correct" way of doing this (because I thought nesting them would be enough) or a way to check if the video has ended in an if statement? Here is my actual code (I'm just posting one snippet, as the rest of it is just this same thing with minute differences):

```
$("#lAbout").click(function() {


    //document.getElementById("block").className = "";

    var op1 = 1;  // initial opacity
    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        if (op1 <= 0.1){
            clearInterval(timer);
            block.style.display = 'none';
            ovideo.style.display = 'none';
            aboutText.style.display = 'none';
            storeText.style.display = 'none';
            FAQText.style.display = 'none';
            eventsText.style.display = 'none';
            right.style.display='block';
            right.play();
        }
        ovideo.style.opacity = op1;
        ovideo.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + op1 * 100 + ")";
        op1 -= op1 * 0.2;
    }, 50);


    $('#right').on('ended',function(){

        lAbout.style.color='#0c8acb';
        lStore.style.color='#fff';
        lFAQ.style.color='#fff';
        lEvents.style.color='#fff';


        var op2 = 0.1;  // initial opacity
        block.style.opacity = op2;
        right.style.display='none';
        block.style.display = 'block';
        aboutText.style.display = 'block';
        //alert('test');
        var timer = setInterval(function () {
            if (op2 >= 1){
                clearInterval(timer);
            }
            block.style.opacity = op2;
            block.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + op2 * 100 + ")";
            op2 += op2 * 0.2;
        }, 50);

    });
    $(this).unbind("click");
});
```

Comment: Can we see more of your actual code please?

Comment: I just posted it @DelightedD0D

Comment: If you make a class object for the video playing that accepts parameters then you can instantiate it upon clicking and each button can send an identifier as to which one was clicked.

Comment: This is somewhat similar to having multiple jQuery datepickers on a page since each datepicker will have to appear based at a different location, based on which item called it.

Comment: Can we see your HTML as well?

Comment: Can you show me an example @Klik

Comment: Sorry bud, I need to catch up on some sleep. Too many work hours lately.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to achieve your goal is to give your links a class, store the index of the clicked link, and play the video. Then, when the video ends, get that index and use it to show the corresponding div.

I left out all your styling code in the below for simplicity's sake.

```js
//attach a handelre to your list items
$('#myList li').click(function() {
  
  // when clicked, store the index of the clicked 
  // list item in a hidden input
  $('#btnIndex').val( $('#myList li').index(this));
  
  // hide any open divs
  $('.noShow').hide();
  
  // show the video
  $('#right').show(); 
  
  //play the video
  // $('#right').show(); // strange, this doesnt work 
  document.getElementById("right").play(); // but this does, weird
  
});


// listen for the video to end
$('#right').on('ended',function(){
     
     // when it does, hide the video
     $('#right').hide();
     
     // get the index of the clicked link from the hidden input
     var btnIndex = $('#btnIndex').val(); 
  
     // show the matching div 
     // the divs need to be in the same order as the links
     $('.noShow:eq('+btnIndex+')').show();
 
});
```

```css
.noShow, #right{
  
  display:none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myList">
  <li>First list item</li>  
  <li>Second list item</li>  
  <li>Third list item</li>  
  <li>Fourth list item</li>

</ul>

  <div class="noShow">You clicked the first list item</div>
  <div class="noShow">You clicked the second list item</div>  
  <div class="noShow">You clicked the third list item</div>  
  <div class="noShow">You clicked the fourth list item</div>

<video id="right" width="400" controls>
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
  <input id="btnIndex" type="hidden" value=""/>
```